# GridBagLayout dynamically use extra space inside panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'd like to create 2 nested border layouts where the inner border layout holds a panel to its center. This panel should have a vertical flow and specific components should grow and together use all available space. In the end this panel should be wrapped by a `JScrollPane`, so it'll get a vertical scrollbar whenever not everything can be shown at its default size. Something along the lines of:

```
+-------------------------------+
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |                       |   |
|   |       growy           |   |
|   |                       |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |                       |   |
|   |       growy           |   |
|   |                       |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

This is how far I got:

[image]

Provided is the following SSCCE:

```
public class SimpleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //createAndShowMigGUI();
                createAndShowSwingGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowSwingGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /* Frame */
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        /* Outer Panel */
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner north"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner south"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner west"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner east"), BorderLayout.EAST);

        /* Text Area */
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea("aHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd");
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        /* Elements Container */
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        /* Grid Bag Constraints */
        GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cons.weightx = 1;
        cons.gridx = 0;

        /* Elements */        
        innerPanel.add(area, cons); // This component should use all available Y-space
        innerPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Test hello"), cons); // Remain as-is
        innerPanel.add(new JTextField("some text field..."), cons); // Remain as-is
        innerPanel.add(new JTextField("some text field PUSH..."), cons); // This component should use all available Y-space 

        /* Add Inner Panel To Outer Panel */
        outerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(innerPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /* Add outer elements */
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer north"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer south"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer west"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer east"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(outerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(40, 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). I would guess you need to use the `fill` contstraint to control the height of the various panels.

Comment: You're missing ScrollablePanel in your SSCCE.

Comment: important question, two groovy could be resizable with the same ratio or not, for parent if it will be laid by GridLaoyut or GridBagLayout

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc changed the original SSCCE, it's of type JPanel anyway.

Comment: @mKorbel yes - the components that need to resized should remain the same ratio. But no all components should resize, some should remain their default height. See original post. So GridLayout it not applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have trouble using one `GridBagConstraints` for all of the components of a `GridBagLayout`, so I created constraints for each of the components.  I can't remember defaults anyway.

The changes included adding weights and setting the proper fill for the `GridBagConstraints`.

[image: Swing GridBagLayout]

Edited to respond to the comment.

When the window (`JFrame`) expands, the `JTextArea`, along with the other components in the window, expands.  When the window shrinks in size, the `JTextArea` would not shrink.  To get around this problem, I put the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane`, and removed and added the `JTextArea` every time the `JFrame` size changed.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleMain {

    protected static final Insets   DEFAULT_INSETS  = new Insets(0, 4, 4, 4);

    protected static JTextArea area;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // createAndShowMigGUI();
                createAndShowSwingGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowSwingGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /* Frame */
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        /* Outer Panel */
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner north"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner south"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner west"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        outerPanel.add(new JTextField("inner east"), BorderLayout.EAST);

        area = setTextArea();

        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);

        /* Elements Container */
        final JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        /* Elements */
        int gridy = 0;

        // This component should use all available Y-space
        addComponent(innerPanel, scrollPane, 0, gridy++, 1, 1, 1.0D, 800.0D,
                DEFAULT_INSETS, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

        // Remain as-is
        JRadioButton helloButton = new JRadioButton("Test hello");
        addComponent(innerPanel, helloButton, 0, gridy++, 1, 1, 1.0D, 1.0D,
                DEFAULT_INSETS, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // Remain as-is
        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField("some text field...");
        addComponent(innerPanel, textField1, 0, gridy++, 1, 1, 1.0D, 1.0D,
                DEFAULT_INSETS, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        // This component should use all available Y-space
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("some text field PUSH...");
        addComponent(innerPanel, textField2, 0, gridy++, 1, 1, 1.0D, 800.0D,
                DEFAULT_INSETS, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

        /* Add Inner Panel To Outer Panel */
        outerPanel.add(new JScrollPane(innerPanel), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /* Add outer elements */
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer north"),
                BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer south"),
                BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer west"),
                BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField("outer east"),
                BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(outerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent event) {
                scrollPane.getViewport().remove(area);
                area = setTextArea();
                scrollPane.getViewport().add(area);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocation(40, 40);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JTextArea setTextArea() {
        /* Text Area */
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        area.setText("aHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "Askjdhuyawduyawd AskjdhuyawduyawdHJAskjdhuyawduyawd "
                + "Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd Askjdhuyawduyawd");

        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        return area;
    }

    private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight,
            double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, weightx, weighty, anchor, fill, insets,
                0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising, however whenever I maximize and minimize the InnerPanel is occupied with a horizontal scrollbar. I'd like to have it with a vertical scrollbar only. Would this also be possible? I implemented scrollable on a JPanel, but that caused the panel to shrink.

Comment: @Mark van Velthoven: The JTextArea won't shrink.  I'm trying a few things, but you might have to use a JTextPane instead.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc although the text area is being a pain (i'd like to have multiline text), this is however the way to go. Thanks for your help!